# How to retrieve full List Of Objects from Firebase that contains another List of String in it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored some **List of person** objects on **Firebase**.I want to retrieve this **full List** into newList of person from database.The class perosn contains another List batch
My class person look like:

```
public class person {
public String name,sid;
public HashMap<String,String> batch;
public int cls;
}
```

The code I have used is:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference fDatabaseRoot = database.getReference("studentsList");
    fDatabaseRoot.orderByChild("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String,person> td = 
                        (HashMap<String,person>)areaSnapshot.getValue();


               // arrayListStudent= (List<person>) td.values();
                 // Log.d("aaa1",arrayListStudent.toString());
            }
            //Log.d("aaa",arrayListStudent.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Where am i getting wrong.Please give some hint and suggestions....
Here is the screenshot of my database structure:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Firebase don't have lists, so use `public HashMap<String, String> batch;`

Comment: I declared the batch attribute of peson using HashMap<String,String> .Now its successfully retrieving the data from firebase.Thanks a lot .But now how to convert this 'td' into a person object so that i can add to arrayListStudent.@DimaRostopira

Comment: person per=areaSnapshot.getValue(person.class); in for loop is also not working....please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studentsListRef = rootRef.child("studentsList");
Query query = studentsListRef.orderByChild("name");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String key1 = ds.child("batch").child("0").getValue(String.class);
            String key2 = ds.child("batch").child("1").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + key1 + " / " + key2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In this way, you'll get the value of `name` and of both fields under `batch`.

Comment: Thank You! this is what i was looking for  :)